# Twig_Environment link to route not working

Tags: symfony, twig

I am having a symfony 4 project, in which I need to render mail templates before sending them via SwiftMailer. I know that the rendering is possible with the renderView() method in the controller (https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html), but for reusability I decided to inject the \Twig_Environment in a service, as can be seen here:
[image]

Then I render the following template and send it via mail:
[image]

The token gets rendered well, but the problem is, that the link to the route 'student_verify' does not work. I have verified that the route name is correct. Is it not possible to render the link in a service? Or does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Please don't post source code as pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this example:

```
<a href="{{ url('student_verify') }}">some text</a>
```